# How long does a complex code take to compile

Tags: code

The [XKCD](http://xkcd.com) comic below suggests that code takes a significant amount of time to compile (Maybe not enough time to stage a sword fight, but you get the idea). However, with the simple Java codes I've worked on, it takes less than 2 seconds to compile 1,000 lines or so in BlueJ, and other IDEs such as Eclipse appear to compile on the fly to some extent.

So under what circumstances (language, code complexity, etc) would a peice of code actually take a long time (say, >1 minute) to compile, or is this comic simply taking creative liberties (which seems unlike xkcd).

[image]

Comment: The full linux kernel takes me 15min for example

Comment: It's kinda hard to quantify this... it depends a lot on your machine but the Linux Kernel can take half an hour to compile, OpenOffice used to take over an hour, and even Firefox took a good amount of time. 1000 lines is almost nothing in terms of software complexity.

Comment: Have a look at Gentoo or Linux From Scratch.

Comment: Depends when the cartoon was drawn. Back in the 1970s, building an IBM 360 operating system used to run overnight. But that used Assembler macros.

Comment: Compile time is in minutes. But a whole build project including unit tests and packaging can take much longer. Depending on the degree of test automation even days.

Comment: The joke the cartoon is making is that the boss has no idea how long it takes to compile, so they are using this as an excuse to goof off.

Comment: @psusi The comic says "legitimately", and I know for a fact that builds can take quite awhile for large projects.

Comment: @DuncanXSimpson's comment I think is spot on.  Its a "build" and not a compile of a single program

Answer (score 1):

There are many factors that contribute to this, but size is a big one. Most modern build systems attempt to perform partial compilation when you change code, so that only the parts that changed are built. However, some tools aren't capable of this.

When compiling millions of lines of .NET code spread over hundreds of projects, your compilation time starts to become quite large. When compiling large libraries while also compiling your own source code, like is often done in the native C/C++ world, you're also going to increase your compile times.

Especially with C and C++, the time spent parsing headers is considerable. It's a very hefty I/O bound process to repeatedly read thousands of headers over and over. This is one reason why the pre-compiled headers technique was created. Of course, an SSD speeds this up greatly as well.

Edit: I forgot to mention that builds often include specialized code generators or DSL compilers. These tools are often custom made in-house projects that aren't as highly optimized as widely used tools, so they can become a bottleneck if used heavily.

Answer (score 1):

With today's technology, it would take a pretty big code-base to need even a minute to compile. But back when dinosaurs (mainframes and large mini-computers - PDP 11/70, 64K of core memory comes to mind) roamed the earth (the mid 70's), even a terminal connected to the only computer for an software team was larger than today's desktop PCs. If you had a 9600 baud connection to it, you were one of the chosen few - most of us were grateful to get upgraded to 2400! The machine was time-shared among the connected users, time-slicing jobs in round-robin fashion.

When a deadline was approaching and everyone was trying to get their piece of the target system compiled, even terminal communication response-times would suffer. In severe cases, the CPU spent as much time swapping jobs to from the disk as it did actually processing them. In those situations, compile times on the order of many minutes were not uncommon.

I remember a similar (worse!) conversation to that cartoon, around 3:30am one night as a deadline approached. The department was on 3 shifts (shift-differential? Screw that!) because the project was so badly man\\\\ er, the only machine for 25 SWEs was so bogged down. I got called out for reading a paper-back at my terminal, trying not to fall asleep, while waiting for a compilation to complete.